# NHibernate QueryOver CASE WHEN calculate on column value

Tags: select, nhibernate, case, queryover

I have been trying to do the following T-SQL in NHibernate QueryOver, but have not succeeded:

```
SELECT Id, SUM(CASE MyValue WHEN 1 THEN Volume ELSE Volume * -1 END)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Id
```

I am trying to sum up all Volume, but for `MyValue=1` should be positive values otherwise negative values. So far I got:

```
 var result = this.Session.QueryOver<MyTable>()
    .Select(Projections.Group<MyTable>(x => x.Id),
    Projections.Conditional(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property<MyTable>(x
        => x.MyValue), '1'),
    Projections.Property<MyTable>(x => x.Volume),
    Projections.Property<MyTable>(x => x.Volume * -1)))
    .List();
```

But as you can imagine NHibernate don't know the column `Volume * -1` , so how do I do this calculation in my CASE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
session.QueryOver<MyTable>()
    .Select(
        Projections.Group<MyTable>(x => x.Id),
        Projections.Sum(
            Projections.Conditional(
                Restrictions.Eq(
                    Projections.Property<MyTable>(x => x.MyValue), 1),
                Projections.Property<MyTable>(x => x.Volume),
                Projections.SqlFunction(
                    new VarArgsSQLFunction("(", "*", ")"),
                    NHibernateUtil.Int32,
                    Projections.Property<MyTable>(x => x.Volume),
                    Projections.Constant(-1)))))
    .List<object[]>();
```

As a rule, QueryOver is pretty terrible at doing arithmetic. As far as I know,  you have to use `VarArgsSQLFunction` to build the multiplication expression.

This generates the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT
    this_.Id as y0_,
    sum((
        case when this_.MyValue = 1 
        then this_.Volume else (this_.Volume*-1) end
    )) as y1_
FROM        
    MyTable this_     
GROUP BY        
    this_.Id
```

Note that you need to use a result transformer paired with a custom DTO here, or use `.List<object[]>`, which will transform the result set into a `List` of `object[]`, each item in the `List` being a result row. You can't just use `.List()` because NHibernate expects to be selecting out entire `MyTable` rows, which you aren't doing here.

You're probably thinking that this is pretty ugly, and I'd agree. You could clean it up a little by refactoring projections into their own variables:

```
IProjection multiplicationProjection = 
    Projections.SqlFunction(
        new VarArgsSQLFunction("(", "*", ")"),
        NHibernateUtil.Int32,
        Projections.Property<MyTable>(t => t.Volume),
        Projections.Constant(-1));

IProjection conditionalProjection = 
    Projections.Conditional(
        Restrictions.Eq(
            Projections.Property<MyTable>(t => t.MyValue), 1),
        Projections.Property<MyTable>(t => t.Volume),
        multiplicationProjection);

session.QueryOver<MyTable>()
    .SelectList(list => list
        .SelectGroup(t => t.Id)
        .Select(Projections.Sum(conditionalProjection)))
    .List<object[]>();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew - I have been reading your blog already, but I don't think this little gem was among them :-)

Comment: @mfas: I don't think so either :). Glad I could help

Comment: I am working with decimals in my real world example, and NHibernate keep telling me that the return types are inconsistent:

"Both true and false projections must return the same types.
But True projection returns: [NHibernate.Type.DecimalType] 
And False projection returns: [NHibernate.Type.DecimalType]"

It makes no sence to me - I have of course changed the type in the SQLFunction to Decimal, and also tried to change the constant to "-1.0m" but to no avail.

Comment: @mfas: Hmm, if I make those changes everything seems to work fine. In fact, if I just change the result of the SqlFunction to `NHibernateUtil.Decimal` I don't get an error. What type does `Volume` have in the C# class?

Comment: I can see the project I'm working on uses NHibernate version 3.3.3.5000. I don't know if this version is buggy in this regard. I will see if I can upgrade to the newest version to see whether that makes a difference. But thanks for testing it for me. And by the way, the property on the entity is also a `decimal`.

Comment: Tried but got an exception: An exception of type 'NHibernate.MappingException' occurred in NHibernate.dll but was not handled in user code No persister
 for: NHibernate.Criterion.AggregateProjection